# Asset Library and Manage Option

Tags: library

I created an Assets Library using SharePoint 2013. I only uploaded image files. I did not upload any audio or video files.

I see that there is no Mange option next to File and Library. Does this Manage option only show up if I upload a video or audio file?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

With video files you might need to change the thumbnail, using a frame of the video itself, with the image there is no need to.